# How to select max, min in same query in slick

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

I want to do this `SELECT MAX(age), MIN(age) FROM users WHERE name = 'Rick'`. The best I came up with involves 2 queries: `Users.filter(_.name === 'Rick').map(_.age).max`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is supported, but first, you'll need to group it. Since you're treating the entire set as a group, group it by `true` and slick will ignore it when generating the SQL:

```
val q = Users.filter(_.name === 'Rick').groupBy { _ => true }.map {
  case (_, group) =>
    (group.map(_.age).max, group.map(_.age).min)
}
```

It should yield you something like this:

```
q.selectStatement
# => select max(x2."age"), min(x2."age") from "Users" x2
```

Another approach you might try would be a union.